# What does operator << do in this line?

Tags: c++, operators

I can not understand what this line does:

```
fBuffer[fByteIndex] += 1 << (fBitIndex - 1);
```

where:

```
unsigned char fBuffer[32];
int fBitIndex;
```

and:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 32; i++ )
     fBuffer[i] = 0;

fBitIndex = 8;
```

What `<<` does there?

Comment: duplication of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281666/what-is-operator-called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281666/what-is-operator-called)

Comment: Voting to reopen.  There are decent answers here and "What does << do" is not the same as "What is << called".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<<` is the left-shift operator, and assuming `fBitIndex` is 8 the code

```
fBuffer[fByteIndex] += 1 << (fBitIndex - 1);
```

is equivalent to

```
fBuffer[fByteIndex] += 128;
```

Why? Because a left-shift means you shift the bits of the value "left"; in your case, `00000001` (1), is shifted left 7 times, becoming `10000000` (128).

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, unsigned char fBuffer[32] means an array of characters in the fBuffer for example fBuffer[4] is 5th char in fBuffer array, right? How this array works with +=1 ?! I am new in C++ and I can`t get it.. for example if I have :                  fBuffer[5] += 1 << (5 - 1); then what happen here ??

Comment: then `fBuffer[5]`'s value is added together with `1 << (5 - 1)`, which is `16`, so the result is equivalent to writing `fBuffer[5] = fBuffer[5] + 16;`

Comment: ..ok .. I got the 1<<(5-1) part, but how is that possible to add a number to an array of chracter?!! I mean fBuffer is an unsigned char, means it contains just characters. So how a number like 16 or 8 can be add to that chracter? .. I think I don`t know a fundamental thing or .. ??

Comment: A "char(acter)" in this context is just a single-byte value. (Bad choice of name, I would say, especially in these days when we use multi-byte character sets like Unicode...) So, each entry in the `fBuffer` array can contain a value between 0 and 255. That these values also correspond to characters in the ASCII character set is just one of VERY many ways to interpret their value.

Answer (score 2):

It's called bit shifting. Each byte is composed of 8 bits (0 or 1). By shifting the bits one time to the left or the right you either multiply the number by 2 or divide it by 2.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit shift.  The decimal number 1 is represented in binary (showing just the lower 8 bits) as

```
00000001
```

If I have

```
int i=1;
int j=i<<1;
```

then I'll be taking that number and shifting it one place to the left.  I'll then have the binary

```
00000010
```

which in decimal is the value 2.  If instead I had

```
int j=i<<6;
```

then I'd get

```
01000000
```

which in decimal would be 128.

Answer (score 1):

It sets bit fBuffer[fByteIndex]

1 << N is just bit addressing.

<< is shift operator and 1<<0 is 0b1, 1<<1 is 0b10 1<<6 is 0b1000000

So based on fByteIndex and fBitIndex , propper bit is set on 1.

In this case where + is used in case that addressing bit is alredy 1, overflow occure, but I think that in your code this is not case and addresd bit is 0 before assignment.