# What is the "<<" operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operators

I couldn't understand what does the operator "<<" means in the following code.

```
    long hashString(char* key)
 {
   int n = strlen(key);
   long h = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
        h = (h << 2) + key[i];
     }
  return abs(h % tablesize);
 }
```

Comment: google for c++ << operator, you're gonna hit bitshifting very quickly.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort." Hmm...

Comment: it's time for the hokey pokey

Comment: the red cross called, he asked if you can possibly stop shooting on them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528840/what-does-operator-do-in-this-line , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281666/what-is-operator-called , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008871/c-what-is-this-syntax-about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the left shift operator. It shifts the value left by 2 bits, effectively multiplying it with 2 to the power of 2 (the shift amount).

```
a << b
```

Is the same as:

```
a * (2 to the power of b)
```

Comment: @vrk001 It was meant to be pseudo-code since there's no power operator. I'll make it more evident that it is pseduo-code and not C++. Thanks for raising this.

Comment: You could use the pow() function. By the way, ^ would have been correct in Visual Basic :-)

Comment: But a library function != language operator... But anyways, it's a moot point now that I've modified my answer :) Still, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bit shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx) (in this context on a `long` variable).

It shifts all bits over by 2 places, resulting in a multiplication by four (just as you would add two digits in a base 10 number to multiply by 100.  To generalize, shifting *n* places will multiply the number by `2^n`).  For example:

```
unsigned int x = 0xA;     // x = 1010  (10 base 10)
unsigned int y = x << 1;  // y = 10100 (20 base 10)
```

You can perform division by two by shifting the bits to the right (i.e., chopping one off the end)

```
unsigned int x = 0xA;     // x = 1010  (10 base 10)
unsigned int y = x >> 1;  // y =  101  (5 base 10)
```

Comment: @Ates Goral: Derp, I shifted the wrong way :).  Thanks.

Comment: Shifting by two bits results in a multiplication/division by 4.

Comment: @AtesGoral: Yeah I gotta quit with the fast trigger responses... I miss the details.

Answer (score 0):

it  is a bitshift operator in c++.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `bitwise shift left` operator that means you assign `h` the value when shifted left by two bits effectively multiplying `h` by 2 to the power of 2:

```
h << 2 == h * (2 ^ 2)
```

You can find more information about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23).

Hint: Next time search http://www.google.com first.